# How to make my local project and repository on Github go separately, intellijidea

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I have created a project on intellij idea. Then publushed it on Gihub via VCS panel.The project has been added to my Github successfully. 
But now I want to make them go separately - project will remain on my computer and project remains on Github, but they shouldn't be arranged.

Comment: What do you mean by "they shouldn't be arranged?"

Comment: As I understand how git works - it creates local repository - and we can push or pull from and to. Now I realized - that I need remove local repo, but repo in Github should remain.

Comment: I believe you can delete the `.git` folder from wherever you initialized the repo.  Git stores all its state inside the `.git` folder.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer helped me. I removed the folder. Then on project settings vcs - I set vcs from "Github" to none